# How to get data as props inside other file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-props

I have a react app

I need on `chart.js` change **arcsData** to data from App.js > rectangle data, it  onClick function (App.js >286) give data (`data: {name: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", DateRange: "January 2002 - April 2002", Duration: 0.3333333333332333}`).

In `App.js` rectangle show `name: value`
I need that `char.js` show `DateRange: value` from **rectangle data**.

To view it, click on Blue circle > Experience > and then opens 7 rectangles > chart is appears when click on rectangle.

Each time on click a rectangle it get new data (can see on console).

Thanks.

Comment: Please try to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and reformulate your question.

Comment: Thank you, I reformed the question.

Comment: So what do you want to do with `DateRange` value ?

Comment: whant to give DateRange value  to chart.js

Comment: but I achieved the result, I moved the date inside the class.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My updates in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/ymp6rrl199

You can see I use the state to render the chart with the `selectedRectangle` `dateRange` value :

```
<div id="chart">
     {this.state.selectedRectangle && (
         <Chart dateRange={this.state.selectedRectangle.DateRange} />
     )}
</div>
```

State is updated `onClick` on a rectangle : (App.js: 297)

```
onClick={() => {
  this.setState({
    selectedRectangle: node.data
  });
}}
```

Then access `dateRange` in chart.js with :

```
this.props.dateRange
```

Please use the state like this instead of all the `forceUpdate()` you do, you should never use it.